# Generate page for each json entry

Tags: 7, search

I'm new to Drupal.
I want to customize the search module in order to show results from an external JSON.
I was able to insert JSON data in the search page, but now I want to generate a page for each result. Something like blog posts.
I'm using the latest Drupal 6 Version.

Please give me some ideas how can I generate the pages for each Drupal result.

Anticipated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [Feeds JSONPath Parser](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_jsonpath_parser) module to parse a JSON feed and insert the objects as a specific content type (e.g. blog posts).

It works well but I'm unsure about your search results, you might just have to set the template to link to each of the content nodes by getting the node based on a specific field that you know will be unique for all of your nodes? e.g. title?

If you don't want to actually store the parsed data as content, and just want to display them as a page, then you'll need to use the [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_menu/6) function. I've linked to API 6 as you noted you were using D6.

Comment: The idea is that I don't want to save the data as blog posts, I just want to read It and to show it first on the search page, and then as individual pages.

Comment: is there a function in drupal that generates static pages? or something like that

Comment: Well `hook_menu()` is basically for 'pages' (or least URLs) -> so you could use that. Check the Examples module and have a look through the Page Examples sub-module inside that module.